# how to add new SubView to rootView controller in SplitViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, subview

I have splitView controller with rootViewController as a table by default i have place a button in rootViewController i want that when that button is clicked it should add subView to rootViewController but it should cover whole screen lighbox or popup we open html , it should cover all the screen rather than only tableArea of rootViewController in splitViewController

```
-(void)onSettingButtonClick{

  NSLog(@"Working click fine");
  UIView*subView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,10,600,400)];

  subView.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];

  [self.view addSubview:subView];
}
```

[image]

Comment: @herzbube can you please help me out in this please

Answer (score 1):

You have two solutions.

**Solution 1 :**

Try to add the view to a window.

To cover the whole view, you have to give subView's dimesions as

```
CGRect subViewBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
UIView*subView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:subViewBounds];
[self.view.window addSubview:subView] ;
```

try to adjust the subviews contents (like labels, buttons, etc.,) according to that.

**Solution 2 :**

Create a new view like backgroundView

```
CGRect backgroundViewBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
UIView*backgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:backgroundViewBounds];
[self.view.window addSubview:backgroundView] ;

CGRect subViewBounds = CGRectMake(0,10,600,400) ;
UIView*subView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:subViewBounds];
[backgroundView addSubview:subView] ;
```

Comment: but i also want that when this view is opened that it opacity should be as so that view can also view previous view

Comment: if i use second code then how will i remove this or get back to original view

Comment: @JanDeveloper : for Solution 1 : If you want to view the previous view, use `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` If you use this, you cannot do interaction with the previouse view.

Comment: @JanDeveloper : For solution 2 : If you want to remove the view, use `[subView removeFromSuperview] ;` and `[backgroundView removeFromSuperview] ;`

Comment: but this way from your code it take portrait bounds i want landscape